# Testing percentages when I may or may not have the original values that give the percentages

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, inference, ancova, percentage

I've found tons written about testing proportions between two groups (Fisher's exact test, $\chi^2$-test, logistic regression, etc) but very little on what happens in a t-test-like setting where the numbers in the t-test are percentages.

I have two populations, $A$ and $B$. From each population, I select individuals and subject them to a test to see what percentage of an allotted time they spend performing a task.

$$\begin{matrix}
A& B\\
3.5 \% & 6.2 \%\\
6.2 \% & 3.5 \%\\
7.1 \% & 5.5 \%\\
5.4 \% & 7.3 \%
\end{matrix}
$$

In a "tidy" data frame...

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Group}& \text{Percent}\\
A & 3.5 \% \\
A & 6.2 \% \\
A & 7.1 \% \\
A & 5.4 \% \\
B & 6.2 \% \\
B & 3.5 \% \\
B & 5.5 \% \\
B & 7.3 \%
\end{matrix}
$$

But this also could be written with the allotted time and time spent on the task.

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Group}& \text{Spent} & \text{Allotted}\\
A& 35 & 100\\
A& 62 & 100\\
A& 71 & 100\\
A& 108 & 200\\
B& 62 & 100\\
B& 35 & 100\\
B& 110 & 200\\
B& 73 & 100
\end{matrix}
$$

My goal is to determine if groups $A$ and $B$ on average spent different percents of time on the task.

The first thought I had was to throw the percentages into the t-test machinery. This feels wrong. My next idea was to regress time spent on group and time allotted and then test the group parameter:

$$\widehat{\text{Spent}}_i = \widehat{\beta}_0 + \widehat{\beta}_1 \text{Alotted}_i + \widehat{\beta}_2 \text{Group}_i
  \\
\\ H_0 : \beta_2 = 0 \text{ vs } H_a : \beta_2 \ne 0 $$

This has an advantage over testing just the time spent by accounting for the fact that more time can be spent on the task if more time is allotted. The drawback is that the percentage is not tested explicitly, and I would expect that to cause controversy; I would have to argue that the test of percentage is implicit in considering the covariate of time allotted (and I am not even sure that this is correct).

**My Questions**:

1) If I have the data frame with the time spent and allotted for each group, what would be the reasonable approaches to determining if $A$ and $B$ spent different percentages of time on the task?

2) If I only have the data on percentages, what are the reasonable approaches to determining if $A$ and $B$ spent different percentages of time on the task?